# use joomla JRoute in external php file

Tags: php, joomla

i want use joomla methods in external php file and i use this code and it's work:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../..' ));

require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'joomla' . DS . 'factory.php' );
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
```

now i want use joomla JRoute  method but it's not work correct in external file. how can use JRoute ?
thank you.

Comment: What's the URL you're trying to use JRoute with? Can you please provide an example in your question?

Comment: example: JRoute::_("index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=$id")

Comment: hope ur setting $id before calling it, neater to make the $url ="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=".$id and the call JRoute::_($url) . Btw what is the end result ur expecting?